# How to check which variable a fuction has returned?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, return

I have just starting my programming journey with Python and I came across this problem that may be completely irrelevant or have an obvious answer.

```
def add(x, y):
    total = x + y
    return total

#This isn't my actual code, but a simplified version to make you understand my question :D
```

So what I would like to know is if it is possible for me to check with an if-statement if the function add() returns the variable total (or which return value it returns if there would be multiple return value options). I will try my best with further explanation if this seems unclear to you.

Comment: No, code outside the `def` does not have access to anything inside it which isn't `global`. (There is a more complex answer which doesn't start with "no" but if you are a beginner, let's ignore that.)

Comment: You can't, not without complex inspection tools. For outside code, `t = add(1, 2)`, `t` is now an integer variable and that's about it. It can't know anything more about it

Comment: No, there is no way to tell from the outside whether you implemented the function like this or as simply a 1-line function body `return (x + y)` - and there shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

Short of some incredibly creative hack, there is no way to check this.

It's not needed though. The specific variable that a function used to return data is an irrelevant implementation detail of the function. The author may change the details of how the function works in the future, which would invalidate anything that relies on undocumented details like that.

Think of it like this: when you use an ATM, do you care which gears turned specifically that lead to your money getting spit out the front? No`*`. All you care about is that the ATM took some input (your card and PIN), and produced an output (your money). The specifics of what happens in the middle are irrelevant to the end user.

It's the same when you're writing and using functions. Functions take some input, and spit out some data (in an ideal world). What happens in the middle is only relevant for debugging when things start to break; not for normal operation of the code.

---

`*` It's a different story though if you're developing an exploit to take advantage of the system. If you're trying to break a function/ATM in a way that benefits you, the specifics of variables/gears involved *may* in fact be relevant. Those details aren't used for normal operation though.